# Elements around the plus sign

Tags: html, css

I can't implement this block as in the screenshot. The essence of the problem, in the center of the plus sign and around its pictures or blocks all this should work correctly on all screens. I would be very grateful if you help to implement.

```css
.center-block{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    &:before{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 128px;
      height: 1px;
      background: #86b4d0;
      top: 180px;
      left: 100px;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    &:after{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 128px;
      height: 1px;
      background: #86b4d0;
      top: 160px;
      left: 100px;
    }
    &__items{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      &:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      a:not(:last-child){
        margin-right: 40px;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="center-block">
<div class="center-block__items">
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="center-block__items">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Note that the code posted is not valid CSS; it's likely LESS or SCSS code. Please post the rendered CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="center-block">
<div class="center-block__items">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#" style="margin-left: -17px;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="center-block__items">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#" style="margin-left: -17px;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .center-block{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    &:before{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 128px;
      height: 1px;
      background: #86b4d0;
      top: 180px;
      left: 100px;
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    &:after{
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      width: 128px;
      height: 1px;
      background: #86b4d0;
      top: 160px;
      left: 100px;
    }
    &__items{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      &:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      a:not(:last-child){
        margin-right: 40px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are upvoted more often than those which just say "Try this" and a bunch of code. Even better to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to allow others to see the code in action without having to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 425px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #808080;
}
.center-block:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 128px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #86b4d0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.center-block:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 128px;
    background: #86b4d0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.center-block__items {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.center-block__items:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.center-block__items a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="center-block">
<div class="center-block__items">
<a href="#">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="center-block__items">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are upvoted more often than those which just say "Try this" and a bunch of code. Even better to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to allow others to see the code in action without having to copy and paste it.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use further transforms to get the rotation right but... Try avoiding transforms on before/after and just calculate the dimensions using calc.

See snippet:

```css
.center-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.center-block:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #86b4d0;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: calc(50% - 64px);
  right: calc(50% - 64px);
}

.center-block:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: #86b4d0;
  top: calc(50% - 64px);
  bottom: calc(50% - 64px);
  left: calc(50% - 1px);
}

.center-block__items {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.center-block__items:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.center-block__items a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-block">
  <div class="center-block__items">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="center-block__items">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```